# How to see if any of a list of strings is contained in another string

Tags: string, hive, hiveql

I have a long string of codes and I want to see if any of a list of codes are in that string. As an example, is there a way to see if 'a' or 'b' are in the following strings:

| String | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| and | true |
| bad | true |
| dog | false |
| lag | true |
| job | true |

My real life example is a long string of diagnosis codes and then a list of codes that I want to see if any of them are in the first string. So I don't want to have to list them all out individually, if possible. The closest thing I can compare it to is a grep with the -f option. grep -Ff file1 file2 will find all rows of file2 that have a match from a line of file1.

file1:

a

b

file2:

and

bad

dog

lag

job

grep -Ff file1 file2 would return:

and

bad

lag

job

Is there something similar in HIVE SQL?

I know in() won't work since I have multiple codes in my first string. Like doesn't seem to be able to handle multiple possible strings. Is there some other function I could try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like`. See the following query:

```
SELECT table2.*
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table2.field1 LIKE concat('%', table1.field1, '%')
```

assuming table1 has same data as file1 and table2 as file2, table2.field1 will be checked against each value of table1.field1 using like pattern matching.